# Multiple paths- what's the best way to do this?

Tags: lightning

We are Realtors.

We want to create a "Buying path", a "Selling path", and a "Flow" path for everyone in our contact list.

Sometimes a person or family is selling their house and buying a new one.  Is there a way to put that family on two different paths and track their progress on both?

We are a tiny company with only two people and I have to teach myself everything as we go with regards to SF, so the simpler the explanation, the better!

Comment: its looks like you have to add more paths Buying Family Path , Selling Family Path etc.

Comment: Path can be associated to a record type, so as long as you can *split* your Account to a buyer vs. seller, you can utilize different paths accordingly. However remember that you will end up creating 3 different records for the same account.